# Problems with Linking my Project C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, linker-errors

I have to compile and run a third person project which is written in C++,
unfortunately I have no experience with C++ and after solving all the com-
piling problems, I face a series of linking problems. 
I receive for a lot of my classes and functions the typical linking error
of "undefined reference to ". As the code is real-
ly huge and composed from a lot of different files, I am presenting to you
the following very small main file in which I try to compile and run using
one of the functions I have problem with and where I also get even in this
small program the same linking error. 
So hopefully if I manage to find the way solving this bit of code I will 
manage with the rest. Before showing you the code itself let me say in ad-
vanced, that in this case I am trying to call a function from cplex.h and
to save you from some suggestions I have already installed correctly cplex
(one thing that I can verify from the fact that I can use some cplec func-
tions and commands without problem) and that I also added cplex as one of 
my external libraries (I use Eclipse IDE), moreover I experience the same lin-
king error for other functions not of cplex.
Finally I have done extensively research the last couple of days in this 
web-site and in general about linking errors without being able to solve 
on my own. As a result anybody's help is pretty much appreciated. 
So here is the code itself:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "/home/used/cplex/include/ilcplex/cplex.h"// that's my cplex.h path
using namespace std;
int main(){
          double temp;
      int a,c;
      CPXENVptr env;// in these two uses of cplex variables I don't get any error
      CPXNETptr net;//
      CPXNETgetdj( env , net , &temp , c , a ); // when I try to use this or any function from cplex I get an linking error
      return( 0 );
}
```

I am also presenting the original function as it is written in cplex.h to see that I do
a proper usage of the function so that I don't confuse the linker with wrong usage of the
function.

```
CPXLIBAPI
int CPXPUBLIC
CPXNETgetdj (CPXCENVptr env, CPXCNETptr net, double *dj, int begin,
            int end);
```

The printer error itself is:

```
Building target: structures
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
g++  -o "structures"  ./src/div.o ./src/prod.o ./src/structures.o   
./src/structures.o: In function `main':
/home/used/workspace/structures/Debug/../src/structures.cpp:21: undefined reference to `CPXNETgetdj'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Well, you're not linking to anything besides your own source files. Is there a cplex library you're supposed to be using with these header files?

Comment: The Cplex library is the cplex.h (if I am not mistaken), moreover because I am really not familiar with linking processes on what else should I link my source files on?

Comment: That's just the header for the library. It defines what functions are available and the datatypes used, not the functions themselves. Cplex should have some source files you either need to compile into a library and link against or include directly in your project.

Comment: I can only find header files in my direcorty exact from some examples that are source files and also .so files.
note that I tried to compile and run one of the examples and I got several mistakes, still I have downloaded and installed Cplex for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#include "/home/used/cplex/include/ilcplex/cplex.h"` would work only if `/` was in sought includes. Also there is no argument responsible for actually including the CPLEX libraries.

I'd suggest changing it to `#include "ilcplex/cplex.h"` for portability and then run it like:

```
g++ -o "structures" ./src/div.o ./src/prod.o ./src/structures.o \
  -I/home/used/cplex/include -L/home/used/cplex/lib/x86-64_debian4.0_4.1/static_pic \
  -lcplex -lilocplex
```

though you have to make what is an actual path to the library (whether `/home/used/cplex/lib/x86-64_debian4.0_4.1/static_pic` is right path) and possibly correct it to the right one.

Based on documentation found [here](http://rcc.its.psu.edu/resources/software/cplex/).

Comment: Check your directories to make sure that there is some `lib` directory - if no your installation might be incomplete. If it is there, try my edited answer.

Comment: I do have lib directory in my cplex files (/home/used/cplex/lib/x86-64_debian4.0_4.1/static_pic), the thing is that since I am using eclipse, I am not pretty sure how to include this library to my program.
Should I try to change the actual make file that is produced automatically from Eclipse? or what?

Comment: Includes -> http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_prop_general_pns_inc.htm&cp=11_4_7_0_4_5_0
Libraries -> http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_prop_general_pns_lib.htm&cp=11_4_7_0_4_5_2 might help you, but first check in command line if it actually works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hints, I solved the problem for CPLEX, as I managed to add the libraries to the linker properly, now I will have to do the same for some other libraries that are inside the project and are creating environments.